# Laravel login with Socialite (google, facebook, etc) and create an access token of my own app

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-socialite

I am using Laravel Social Authentication with Socialite, I can login successful, but I want to create the access token of my own app, but not the google, twitter and facebook token.

I can create the access token, but it creates everytime when the user login with Socialite. What I want is the token will be created when the user first login with Socialite. Also, the 'user_id' is missing when the token created.

Here's my loginController

```
   public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
   {
       try {
           $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();
       } catch (Exception $e) {
           return redirect('/login');
      }
       $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user, $provider);

        Auth::login($authUser,false);

        $user = User::find($authUser['user_id']);

        return $this->getBearerTokenByUser($user, 3, true);
   //    return redirect($this->redirectTo);
      return $user;
  }


   public function findOrCreateUser($providerUser, $provider)
   {
       $account = SocialProvider::whereProviderName($provider)
                  ->whereProviderId($providerUser->getId())
                  ->first();

       if ($account) {
          return $account->user;
       } else {
           $user = User::whereEmail($providerUser->getEmail())->first();

           if (! $user) {
               $user = User::firstOrCreate([
                   'email' => $providerUser->getEmail(),
                   'first_name'  => $providerUser->getName(),

               ]);
           }

           $user->socialProviders()->create([
               'provider_id'   => $providerUser->getId(),
              'provider_name' => $provider,
          ]);
       return $user;
   }
```

Here is the database data [table 'oauth_access_tokens'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJPY5.png)
[table 'users_key'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Uo46.png)

The user_id is missing and the tokens were created twice for the same person (login with google).

The user doesn't have the password because it authentication with Socialite.

Answer (score 1):

you might wanna do some thing like

```
// Retrieve user by email, or create it with the email and first_name attributes...

User::firstOrCreate(
  ['email' => $providerUser->getEmail()],
  ['first_name'  => $providerUser->getName()]
]);
```

Comment: Yep, I can create a new user by retrieving their email or something, but what I want to do is create a new user AND generate the access token of my app for this new user.

Comment: and is your email address field set as unique in the database?

Comment: Cool. That means you won't be able to create the second record with same email address right because of your database constraint.

Comment: Yes, in 'user' table, it just create once, but in 'oauth_access_tokens' table, it create every time it login...that's the problem, I want one token for one user.

Comment: So rather than doing `User::firstOrCreate` you might have to update existing relationship for saved users `$user->socialProviders()->update([ 'provider_id'   => $providerUser->getId(),provider_name' => $provider]);`